# Django allauth redirects to signup

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using the django all-auth package to allow people to login through g+ oauth2. The problem is that on the server, logging in causes it to redirect to the /accounts/social/signup page, instead of directly logging in and going back to the home page.

Here's the required code details

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/google/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
    'SCOPE': [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
     ],
     'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}
    }
}
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'lostndfound.views.LoginAdapter'
```

lostndfound.views

```
class LoginAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        user = sociallogin.account.user
        if user.email.split('@')[-1] not in settings.ALLOWED_LOGIN_HOSTS:
            messages.error(request, "You can login only through an *** account.")
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home')))
```

Comment: What have you tried exactly? It seems you tried to create a new account via g+ and then you were redirect to sign_up. 

In the doc: # SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True

# Attempt to bypass the signup form by using fields (e.g. username, email) retrieved from the social account provider. If a conflict arises due to a duplicate e-mail address the signup form will still kick in.

Do you have more information to see what's wrong with your settings?

Comment: @abrunet I don't need any additional information, and hence don't require a signup form. It had been working fine up until now, automagically creating a user, and logging it in. And this is what I want. However, I don't know what I did to mess this up.

Comment: Don't you have anything to follow the change in your code? :/ If you're not logged in, something may have failed. Is the account created? Can you check if google has seen the request and added it into your allowed app etc.. Have you done some package upgrade recently?

Comment: @abrunet Actually since some hook within the allauth library is redirecting to the signup page, I can't follow the flow. However what I do know is that google does indeed send a callback, but the user does not get added as seen in the admin site

Comment: Maybe this is going to sound stupid, but do you have the message framework on your signup template? I think I remember that django allauth add a message when it fails/success on login. You might get some info. I can't help you much more :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had used my email id I was trying to login through as the email id of the superuser of the admin site. This was causing a conflict as the email was not unique. I simply changed my email of the superuser.

Comment: If you do not have that email mentioned in User objects, try allauth's `Email addresses`.

Comment: darkryder I am presently facing the same issue but unable to resolve it. It would be great it you could help me!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Email id you tried to log in with google is previously stored in DB in any other way. If there then remove it and try once more.